# Ring of integers in a cubic extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, integer-rings

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, with $\alpha^3=10$. How can be proved that
$$\frac{\alpha^2+\alpha+1}{3}$$
is in $O_L$, the ring of integers of $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Method One: Linear Algebra*. Set $\beta=(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)/3$. Compute $\beta^2$ and $\beta^3$, writing the results in the form $\square\alpha^2+\square\alpha+\square$. Set $a\beta^3+b\beta^2+c\beta+d=0$, scale by $3$, write as $\square\alpha^2+\square\alpha+\square=0$, set each $\square=0$ for a system of $3$ linear equations in $4$ variables. Use elimination and substitution, or more sophisticated techniques if desired, for a solution, scaling so $a=1$ and $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$.

*Method Two: Galois Theory*. The cube roots of $10$ are $\alpha,\omega\alpha,\omega^2\alpha$ so these must be its conjugates under Galois action $\sigma$. Write down $\sigma\beta$ and $\sigma^2\beta$ then expand $(x-\beta)(x-\sigma\beta)(x-\sigma^2\beta)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Factoring $10-1$ in two different ways yields the equality

$$\frac{\alpha^2+\alpha+1}{3}=\frac{3}{\alpha-1}=\beta.$$

Rescale $(1+3/\beta)^3=10$ so $\beta$ satisfies an integer-coefficient polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

It's a root of $x^3-x^2-3x-3$, which is a polynomial with integer coefficients. To see this, use the geometric series formula to sum $\alpha^2+\alpha+1$ and play around with the resulting expression.

Comment: You needn't play with Galois conjugates. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed, an element of a finite extension is algebraic if and only if its minimal polynomial has $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Usually you get the minimal polynomial by multiplying conjugates together. But my Galois theory is bad. I edited something better in.

Comment: I was commenting not on how you found the minimal polynomial, but the phrasing. You made it sound like if you had messed around with the Galois conjugates, found the minimal polynomial, and that hadn't been a Z-coefficiented poly, you would have searched for another. Oh well, it was just a comment! +1